# PHP and MYSQL: Why does A work and B not work?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql5

First of all, I am using the DATE_ADD function for MySQL. When trying to use `$sqlA` in php, it saids syntax error for some reason (mainly the area after WHERE). Why?

```
$sqlA = "SELECT $column_name FROM $table_name WHERE Date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), - INTERVAL 3 DAY)";
```

However, it works without DATE_ADD:

```
$sqlB = "SELECT column FROM table WHERE Date >=  CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY ";
```

Notice I put the column name and table name in `$sqlB`? Well, I tried substituting it now with PHP and this fails. It says syntax error, why?

```
$sqlC = "SELECT $column_name FROM $table_name WHERE Date >=  CURDATE()-INTERVAL 3 DAY";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have the minus sign in front of `INTERVAL`.  Use `DATE_SUB` instead.